# Force HTTPS Redirect on URL and Subfolders, as well as Remove WWW and .HTML

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel

I'm currently using the following .htaccess configuration to enforce HTTPS protocol, and remove WWW prefix.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However, it doesn't function with subfolders, **e.g. www.abc.com/projectdirectory/index.html**

Is there a way to enforce this rule across entire website structure? So, if the user manually types into the URL field: *www.abc.com/**projectdirectory**/index.html* or *www.abc.com/projectdirectory/**projectx**/index.html*, it adds HTTPS protocol to the URL and removes WWW.

In addition, is there a way to remove .HTML? 
I've used this snippet before, and it affected the recognition of .JS, .PHP files.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the .html extension you will need an .htaccess rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Use the above mentioned rule instead of the one you have posted here.

You could add a **RewriteBase /** after **RewriteEngine On** so your **.htaccess** will look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```